# Adding another date using the date repeat API

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using the Date Repeat API in Drupal 7 to create an interface for a user to add in a recurring event. As it comes out of the box, it only allows for one date, then you have to save the node and re-edit. I've commented out the `date_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter()` in `date.module` which hides the multiples values option which I thought would allow the associated API to show the 'Add another item'  button. When I go into the 'manage fields' form in the Content Type, I've set the form to 'unlimited' values and saved it. However when I load the content type, the normal date which still has the 'Add another item ' button but the recurring date time does not.

I'm trying to add this since the event that it is attached to might well have a second recurring time for that event, for example it happens every Monday and every second Wednesday. Whilst I am aware that you can do this through saving and re-editing, from a UI perspective it would easier to allow a user to add more than one form of recurring event if needs require.

I'd be grateful for any guidance in solving this issue. Thanks.

---

Update: I've been doing some more digging and it appears that the 'repeat' code is a form linked off the `date_request_api`, but I cannot see why the field created in the *Content Type* admin UI does not appear to pick up on the multiple values setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the repeat option in the field configuration, the Date module then declares to the Field API that it handles multiple values. There is a lot of [discussion about it](https://www.drupal.org/node/213847) on drupal.org but sadly no patches for Drupal 7.